# Why am I getting this invalid table name error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to create a temporary table but it's showing me this error:

> ORA-00903: invalid table name.

What did I did wrongly? This is what I did:

```
create private temporary table PID 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
as
select distinct
    lot_id,
    ssr.run_oid,
    process_id
from sigma.sigma_run ssr
inner join sigma.sigma_lot ssl on ssl.run_oid = ssr.run_oid
```

Comment: By default a private temporary table must be prefixed with `ORA$PTT_`

Comment: @Brian How do I do that? I'm new to oracle sql developer.

Comment: You put what @Brian wrote in front of the temporary table name, with them connected by the `_` to make one word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`CREATE TABLE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6):

> #### Restrictions on Private Temporary Tables
>
> In addition to the general limitations of temporary tables, private temporary tables are subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The name of private temporary tables must always be prefixed with whatever is defined with the `init.ora` parameter `PRIVATE_TEMP_TABLE_PREFIX`. The default is `ORA$PTT_`.

So you need to use:

```sql
create private temporary table ORA$PTT_PID 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION
AS
select distinct
    lot_id,
    ssr.run_oid,
    process_id
from sigma.sigma_run ssr
inner join sigma.sigma_lot ssl on ssl.run_oid = ssr.run_oid
```

*Note: You also want `PRESERVE DEFINITION` and not `PRESERVE ROWS`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5a5eREUq)